# How to implement cross-reference among 3+ records?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this structure

```
(int)id | (text)title | (text)description | (int)related
```

and a query which joins the table with itself

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.title as relatedTitle
FROM mytable t1 LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.related=t1.id
```

to produce in one SELECT list like this

**`title:` Hi, `description:` informal greetings, `see also:` Hello**

When a new record is stored into the table, only one other record can be referenced

[image: one-way reference]

What I try to achieve is cross reference

[image: cross-reference]

which can be among 2-5 objects

[image: multi cross-reference]

All objects should be cross referenced in every combination. I want this feature: **if `related` is set, the script should automagically create cross reference in the related records. If record is deleted, the script should update the reference in the related records.**

For 3+ records cross referenced, I am considering this joining table

```
(int)id | (int)related
```

but it would be 20 records for 5 cross referenced objects. I could also create one-column table

```
(varchar)relatedList
```

but how to create the left join and how to delete relations in this structure? Or should I try some other approach like triggers, views or temporary tables? I want to avoid redundance and keep it as simple as possible and just can't figure this out.

Comment: Please be patient: I have to leave for some time now and I need to think about your answers with concentration. (I will delete this comment when I'm back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your groups are typically bigger than 2, then you should create a list of groups - if A is connected to B and C it makes a group A,B,C.

So, as soon as a relation is inserted, you check if the related item is already in a group. If it is set, then the "new" related entry is also in that group.

If not, you just created a new group which contains those two Items.

So if from your Example "Hi" is alone, and "Ho" gets connected to "Hi", then both form a new group.
When "Ahoi" also gets into connection to "Hi", it just needs to copy the group_id from Hi.

EDIT: according to the comment asking for the select:

The structure:

```
table groups: group_id int not null primary key auto_increment, created_tmstmp timestamp
table items: item_id int, group_id int default null
```

The select:

```
select * from items i1 
inner join items i2 on i2.item_id != i1.item_id 
      and i2.group_id = i1.group_id 
where i1.id = <given item>.
```

The insert of a relation may be connected to insert of one of the Items, this depends on the scenario of the Thread Owner. If it is a new relation for both entries then a new group is inserted.

Other questions are: is an item only in one group? Otherwise one needs a item_group table to connect a item to more then one group.

No join on strings, sorry for the possibility to be understood so cruelly. ;-)

Comment: And what about the selects? To join the words table twice on the "groups table" with string comparison would have poor benchmark on 10k+ records I guess. Or how would you compose the query?

Comment: No string join, I have added the query.

Comment: Ah, it is Jan itself, so: you want to ask _if_ two Items are connected or get the list of connected items? Are the Connections distinct? I mean is an entry only in _one_ list of connections?

Comment: This seems to be promising, let me think about it.

Comment: Yea, you are the Lord of the queries!

Answer (score 0):

Go with this one:

```
(int)id | (int)related
```

It is a very common approach.

If you use the list approach, your SQL queries will be extremely complicated.

Generally, SQL engines are very good at optimizing queries against tables with very large numbers of rows, so at most reasonable hardware, you shouldn't have to worry about millions of rows in such table. (Depending on what you are going to use it for, of course.)

To model non-directed edges, always insert the lowest id in the `id` column (you can add a `CHECK` constraint to enforce this). By doing this, you'll eliminate half of the tuples.

If you run into performance issues because you want to model a complete graph, consider only using the table above for "neighbor" connections, calculate the completion of the graph and insert it into a table that contains partitions of all items, one partition for each complete subgraph:

```
(int)partition | (int)id
```

Lets take a look at an example. Given the items (1 .. 8) and the edges (1, 2), (1, 3), (4, 3), (6, 5), (6, 7) - not including the edges that are required to complete the graph, you get

```
(int)id | (int)related
      1 |            2
      1 |            3
      3 |            4
      5 |            6
      6 |            7
```

(And no records with the item 8.)

And then in the partition table:

```
(int)partition | (int)id
             1 |       1
             1 |       2
             1 |       3
             1 |       4
             2 |       5
             2 |       6
             2 |       7
             3 |       8
```

To check if an item is related to another item will only be a self-join on the partition table, but changing the graph requires manipulation of both tables.

Comment: Say I am inserting a record with ID 10, which should be related with record 1, which is related with record 2. There are already (1,2), (2,1) tuples, I need to insert (1,10),(10,1),(2,10),(10,2). And vice versa: when deleting record 2, I need to delete 4 items. This should be easy: `DELETE FROM relations WHERE id=2 OR related=2`. But how about inserting the tuples?

Comment: So the edges are always non-directed?

Comment: Complete as in if a ~ b and b ~ c then a ~ c?

Comment: Thank you for your effort so far. So much for the implementation of complete graph, but what about the queries? To add and remove relation with a single query if possible? I don't have a clue with this structure.

Comment: Add and remove relations can be done with one query if you write triggers that maintain the partition table. In that case, it's just adding and removing from the edge table as you would normally (except you have to order the item ids).

Comment: @flaschenpost is writing an answer that uses the same principles.

Answer (score 0):

As mzedeler said a many-to-many relation is usually realized using a join table. Please consider using a separate id column so you'd get

```
Id,rel1,rel2
```

That way frameworks like hibernate would know what to do. This makes even more sense considering the fact that you are talking about a transitive and symmetric relation. So for 4 related items 3 entries could suffice if your script does some basic inference. Of course you would need to fill the gap in a given relation chain if a connecting entry where removed.